# Equation for real number to binary conversion

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binary

A real number can be converted into binary as given in the attached figure. How can we represent this process using an equation?

[The method of converting a real number to binary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMsvT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $p>1$ be an integer.  Is this what you are asking for (with $p=2$)
$$x=\text{sign}(x)\,\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\,{\Big(\left\lfloor p^{-k}\, |x|\right\rfloor\text{ mod }p\Big)}{p^k}\,?$$

Comment: Since you took $x$'s sign out front, shouldn't the inner $x$ be $|x|$ ?

Comment: Yep, I forgot.  Thanks.

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks.